# How to manipulate with incremental names of fields?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to manipulate with incremental names of fields?
For example:

```
 myBitmapField1
 myBitmapField2
 myBitmapField3
 ...
```

Is a way to add them to FieldManager in a way like this or similar:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 1000)
 {
 i = i + 1;
 if (myCounter == i)
 myVerticalFieldManager.add(_myBitmapField[i]);
 }
   ...
```

There is a way to manipulate with incremental names of file names like this:

```
 myBitmapField.setBitmap(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("a" + myCounter + ".png"));
```

But I need to manipulate with names of **fields** ! How could I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, don't - use an array (or possibly a `List`) instead. If you *have* to use names, create an appropriate `Map` (e.g. a `HashMap`) from names to values.

While you *can* access fields using reflection - at least in "normal" Java - it would be a poor design here. You've got multiple related values, so use a collection... it's as simple as that.

Comment: it's blackberry java, so java-me. No field reflection is allowed.

Comment: @Michael: I suspected that might be the case. In this case it's a benefit, as it'll force a cleaner design than using reflection :)

Comment: Array, List, and HashMap --- can they manipulate with BitmapFields?  (Most examples i see around on the web are manipulating with strings).

Comment: You can have an array of anything. Or a list of anything, or a hashmap of anything to anything. They are all just container types, that will contain other objects, such as BitmapFields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the fields in a manager by name. You can instead access them by field position. Perhaps that will do for what you need.