# How can I using Array, List ,HashMap or HashSet - create long list of BitmapFields? (Java, Blackberry)

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, hashmap

I need to:   1) create **long** list of BitmapFields and 2) add them to the screen. Since list is long I want to use some short automated method like Loop or similar:

```
while (i < 1000)
 {
 i = i + 1;
 myBitmapField[i].setBitmap(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("picture" + i+ ".png"));
 myVerticalFieldManager.add(_myBitmapField[i]);
 }
```

But it seems that I cannot assign a index **i** to a name of BitmapField *myBitmapField[**i**]*, only to a name of the file itself.

So how can I create a long list of BitmapFields ? Can i use List, Array, HashMap, or HashSet for this purpose?  An example welcome.  Thanks a lot!     (Blackberry, Java)

Comment: I'm missing something. What's failing exactly? (Also, I don't know whether adding 1000 fields to a manager is such a good idea, regardless of whether we can solve your loading problem.)

Comment: This is really similar to a previous question of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414204/how-to-manipulate-with-incremental-names-of-fields).  Editing your previous question to be clearer is better than posting a new question.

Comment: Hmm this question is a bit different. @Ted, The problem is that when i write "myBitmapField[i]" I get an error. It seems that I cannot assign a index i to a name of BitmapField. But i might be wrong, there fore asking.

Comment: What's the declaration of `myBitmapField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting that error, that just means that `myBitmapField` isn't declared as an array type. You'll want to declare it as an array, e.g:

```
BitmapField[] myBitmapField = new BitmapField[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    myBitmapField[i] = new BitmapField();
}
```

You could in principle use any of the data types you listed, though only an array can be indexed with the `[...]` syntax. You just have to change the declaration initialization to use whatever data type you want. And if you use a type that doesn't support indexes you'll have to change your index to use the .get method on the data type you choose.  But I'm not sure why you'd want to use anything other than an array...

And at that point you might as well combine the above loop with your existing loop, so that you only have one loop.

Also, if you have 1000 images being displayed, you will probably have **horrible** performance. BlackBerry has trouble dealing with 1000 fields of any type in a list, and images can be fairly heavyweight. It may even take so long to load on some devices that the BlackBerry will think your app is hanging and terminate it. Not to mention that it isn't very good from a UI perspective to have so many items on a small mobile screen, since no user would be able to navigate to all of them in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: Excellent @Laepdjek it did the trick! I didn't know that i need to declare it as array type, therefore couldn't understand what @Ted meant when he asked about declaration. @Paul your code also worked perfectly, thanks a lot! I oped for array method since i need all these BitmapFields to be clickable buttons and foud it more simple to do with array..

Comment: BTW adding 1000 click-able bitmapFields 13X13 size to a screen is a breeze! it takes no time and doesnt crash at all! and it looks nice too:)

Comment: I don't think the performance will be horrible - if bitmaps will be displayed by a ListField, because then only the visible bitmaps will matter...

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < myBitmapField.length; i++) is slightly better

Comment: Good point Alexander. When I had tried something similar I had bad performance, but now that I think about it that may have been because I had a lot of memory intensive things going on behind the scenes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your way, doesn't seem to for for me either. try this:

```
private pics = new Vector();

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++{

    BitmapField temp = new BitmapField();
    pics.addElement(temp);
    ((BitmapField)pics.elementAt(i)).setBitmap(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("picture" + i + ".png"));
    add((BitmapField)pics.elementAt(i));

}
```

Also i agree with @Ted about the 1000 fields. good luck, let us know.